# Why am I getting DEVELOPER_ERROR response code when connecting my BillingClient?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-app-signing, android-app-bundle

```
/**
 * Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate that the application was
 * not correctly signed or properly set up for In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have
 * the necessary permissions in its manifest
 */
int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5;
```

---

I am using Google Play Signing - so I upload App Bundles for releases. I'm wondering if that could somehow be related? (since Google Play is using its own signing key on their backend vs a local key)

I have the com.android.vending.BILLING permission in my manifest, and I'm able to use "test cards" with debug builds successfully. I only noticed this problem through Bugsnag reports where I am logging failure events.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: did you use the correct keys? Play App Signing gives you two keys, one that you use to sign your app with, and one that Google will sign your app with. The 2nd key is the one you want registered to all key-sig-related matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google Cloud Console, you need to configure the API credentials to whitelist your package name and the certificate. The certificate is the one that is listed as "App Signing certificate" in the "App Signing" page in the Play Console.

Answer (score 1):

When [billingClient.startConnection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#startConnection(com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener)) is performed multiple times in a short period of time, the value of [billingResult.responseCode](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingResult#getResponseCode()) becomes [DEVELOPER_ERROR](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode#DEVELOPER_ERROR).

Comment: I could confirm that it was my case.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when using `BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsnyc()`, where I got an empty BillingResult debug message and `DEVELOPER_ERROR` as a ResponseCode.

Turns out I passed `BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTION` instead of `BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS` to the function as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchasesAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener)).

So be sure to **double check** your function **parameters**!

Answer (score -1):

Modded/tampered APKs will trigger this error due to a different signature.